# Second level caching in hibernate while migrating from JBoss to TomEE

Tags: java, hibernate, jta, apache-tomee, second-level-cache

I need to migrate my application built in GWT from Jboss to tomEE. The application has second level caching enabled in hibernate using Jboss cache. Is it possible to use Jboss cache in tomEE or do I have to find an alternative? If possible, can anyone please help me with the configuration of hibernate.cfg.xml? Below is the configuration

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.sybase.jdbc3.jdc.Sybdriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">xyz...</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">xyz..</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xyz..</property>
    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect</property>
    <property name="generate_statistics">false</property>       
    <property name="jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset">false</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.jbc.JBossCacheRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="cache.use_minimal_puts">true</property>
    <property name="cache.use_structured_entries">true</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.jbc2.JndiMultiplexedJBossCacheRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="cache.region.jbc2.cachefactory">java:CacheManager</property>
    <property name="cache.region.jbc2.cfg.entity">mvcc-entity</property>
    <property name="cache.region.jbc2.cfg.collection">mvcc-entity</property>
    <property name="cache.region.jbc2.cfg.query">local-query</property>

    <mapping resource="book.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried this config? Any problems? Have you considered using Wildfly? Infinispan (a successor to JBoss Cache) is default cache provider there, with full clustering and transaction/non-transactional support.

Comment: I did try this config and added jboss cache specific jars like jgroups.jar, jboss-cache.jar and many others. There's an error while finding java:CacheManager in jndi. I suspect a configuration mismatch somewhere.

Comment: Recently I wrote some tutorials on using Infinispan as Hibernate second level cache provider. Given that you're on tomEE, the [standalone tutorial](http://infinispan.org/tutorials/simple/hibernate-cache-local/) would be the best for you to try out. It uses latest Hibernate 5.3 and JPA though...

Answer (score 0):

We cannot achieve the second level caching using JBoss cache in TomEE. We have implemented a similar caching mechanism using Ehcache which is a little slow but works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="cache.region.jbc2.cfg.entity">mvcc-entity</property>
<property name="cache.region.jbc2.cfg.collection">mvcc-entity</property>
<property name="cache.region.jbc2.cfg.query">local-query</property>
```

We see that entity, collection, and query caching are enabled by using JBoss cache implementation specific to JBoss server. In the case of TomEE, we cannot have the same configuration. You would have to implement a different caching technique using different caching technologies available and match it with the usage of second-level cache(like say read-only, read-write, transactional etc.). In a similar setup, I had used "Ehcache" and that had solved the problem.